# Writing audio from AVAsset to AVAudioPCMBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avaudiopcmbuffer

I am a bit lost, trying to write the audio track of a video file that I loaded into an AVAsset into a AVAudioPCMBuffer.

I found some tutorials in C but I only know swift.
Does anybody know how to do it?

Would be great!